# SVN commit is very slow

Tags: svn, upload, internet-speed, commit

I have tried a lot of fixes for this problem, and it is driving

me nuts. So here goes, I hope someone can please help!

- I am using SVN to upload a 500MB file and it is using only 17% of my
  upload speed, making commits very slow (2.5 Mbits/sec, or about 450 kbtes/sec).
- When I use WinSCP it uploads at 20 Mbits/sec to the SAME HOST.
- When I use a second PC connected to the SAME ROUTER in the same office, it SVN commits to the SAME HOST at 20Mbits/sec (about 2,500 kbtes/sec).
- All of my colleagues in their remote homes can SVN commit at a speed that matches their WinSCP connection speed.
- Disabling windows firewall and F-secure make no difference
- Changing the cable makes no difference
- Reinstalling the network card driver makes no difference

[Demo showing the different upload speeds WinSCP vs SVN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hv3g.png)

Tortoise SVN version:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.11.1, Build 28492 - 64 Bit , 2019/01/08 21:40:39
ipv6 enabled
Subversion 1.11.1, -release apr 1.6.5 apr-util 1.6.1
serf 1.3.9 OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
zlib 1.2.11 SQLite 3.23.1
```

ISP Broadband speed (tested):
    380Mbits/sec DL and 20Mbits/sec upload speed.

Router connection: 
    brand new cat 6 cable, works fine on second PC

Motherboard:
    MSI Z87-G45 GAMING (MS-7821) (SOCKET 0)

Network card:
    Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet controller
There seems to be an issue here, in that the Network card

reports IPv6 is not functioning?
[Network card properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2aSs.jpg)

Questions:

1. What can I do to diagnose the faulty commit speed?
2. Any suggested fixes?

Thank you!

Comment: the router does not support ipv6, and the working PC with perfect upload speed also has the same ethernet settings as the PC with the problem.

Comment: I have now replaced the router / cable / network card. Still got the speed throttle. I am now looking closely at a windows re-install, or even an upgrade to windows 10 (from win 7 64 bit pro). and after that, perhaps a new motherboard...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Last Windows 7 update  (approx March 12 2019) broke SVN upload speed for windows 7 64bit pro.
My laptop also had thesame problem.
Upgrading to Windows 10 fixed it instantly.